# Is using UNIQUE in SQL Inefficient?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to SQL and have started learning Postgres. I want to create a database in which one of the column of table in that database is `email`. Now since I will be using email to uniquely identify the person for sign-up & logging in, I used UNIQUE command while creating the table so that if an account already exists with that email I will pass an error. But will this be efficient in large databases?

Here is the screenshot of the SQL command I have used.
[image: Here is the screenshot of the SQL command I have used.]

Comment: Compared to *any other way you might be contemplating of enforcing uniqueness*, it's probably one of the more efficient.

Comment: Definitions of "efficient" and "large" are needed, at a minimum, to answer this with anything except speculation.

Comment: If you ever need to search by `email` you'll have to add an index on that field anyway. In almost all database products a `UNIQUE` constraint is implemented by creating a unique index

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by efficient?  A `unique` constraint or index adds overhead to prevent duplicates.  This overhead is needed on `insert`s or `update`s on the affected columns.

How much overhead?  Well a uniqueness is validating by using an index.  On most databases, looking up a value in an index can be quite fast and usually does not pose a significant performance issue.  Of course, such overhead can sometimes be important, particularly on very busy databases with lots of data changes (think dozens or hundreds of transactions per second).

In general, the size of the table is going to have little impact on the performance -- well, indexes do slow down a little bit (but hardly noticeable) as tables get bigger, assuming there is sufficient memory.

On the other hand, the cost of not having data integrity can be much larger -- affecting the performance and quality of queries that run on the data.